# NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

When I start httpd it says:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

I have however configured a virtualhost as followed:

httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Include /etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/
```

There's a symbolic link in the sites-enabled directory:

```
900-tennisconnect.eu.vhost -> /etc/httpd/conf/sites-available/tennisconnect.eu.vhost
```

The error is probably here (in the tennisconnect.eu.vhost file):

```
# Apache did not start after modifying this vhost file.
# Please check file /etc/httpd/conf/sites-available/tennisconnect.eu.vhost.err for     syntax errors.
```

It says apache did not start? But when I do "service httpd status" it says the service is running

Last but not least, the tennisconnect.eu.vhost.err file:

```
<Directory /var/www/tennisconnect.eu>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tennisconnect.eu/web

    ServerName tennisconnect.eu
    ServerAlias *.tennisconnect.eu
    ServerAdmin webmaster@tennisconnect.eu

    ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/tennisconnect.eu/error.log

    Alias /error/ "/var/www/tennisconnect.eu/web/error/"
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
    ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/tennisconnect.eu/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    # php as fast-cgi enabled
    # For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcg$
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        IdleTimeout 300
        ProcessLifeTime 3600
        # MaxProcessCount 1000
        DefaultMinClassProcessCount 0
        DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 100
        IPCConnectTimeout 3
        IPCCommTimeout 360
        BusyTimeout 300
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /var/www/tennisconnect.eu/web>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # add support for apache mpm_itk
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId web1 client1
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
        # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/webdav>
            <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
        DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp/DavLock
        # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
        # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
        # WEBDAV BEGIN
        # WEBDAV END
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

This is what httpd -S returns:

```
[Sat Aug 18 14:52:26 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Sat Aug 18 14:52:26 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:8081         uk2be.com (/etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/000-apps.vhost:10)
*:8080                 is a NameVirtualHost
default server uk2be.com (/etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost:10)
port 8080 namevhost uk2be.com (/etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost:10)
Syntax OK
```

---

Found this is in my apache log:

```
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/ispconfig/server/scripts/vlogger line 148.
piped log program ' /usr/local/ispconfig/server/scripts/vlogger -s access.log -t  "%Y%m%d-access.log" /var/log/ispconfig/httpd' failed unexpectedly
Can't locate Date/Format.pm in @INC (@INC contains:  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386- linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8) at /usr/local/ispconfig/server/scripts/vlogger line 148.
```

---

New error in apache log, the above one is solved :)

```
[Sat Aug 18 23:15:01 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
```

Comment: look at /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/tennisconnect.eu/error.log ?

Comment: That is an empty file

Comment: Good new, so the log directory exists. httpd -S gives any clue?

Comment: Updated my first post with what httpd -S returned

Comment: Is apache listening on port 443 and 80? You can figure out by typing netstat -ntlp if you are using linux

Comment: it's listening on port 80, but not on 443 (but that's not really necessary). I updated what's in httpd.conf in my first post (Listen 80)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4553/discussion-between-eric-dannielou-and-mattyh88)

Comment: Where was the "Apache did not start after modifying this vhost file." note, exactly?  Sounds like ISPConfig is doing something goofy.

Comment: In the tennisconnect.eu.vhost file. I edited my first post again with an error I've found in the apache log

Comment: I've installed perl-TimeDate and that solved the first issue. Now I'm getting an other error which is in my first post :)

Comment: Solved this one too. Had to create an index.html file in /var/www/html but when I go to tennisconnect.eu it just shows that html file I just created. But I'd like to show the index.html file from /var/www/tennisconnect.eu/web